# Importing %m.%Y from excel file into R

Tags: r, excel, date, import, format

I am trying to import a excel file into R, and one of the columns is %m.%Y. In excel it looks like this:

5.2017
5.2017
5.2017
5.2017
2.2017
9.2017

and when I import it into R using readxlsx it comes out as a character variable:

5.2016999999999998
5.2016999999999998
5.2016999999999998
5.2016999999999998
2.2017000000000002
9.2017000000000007

Any ideas on how to import the data so that I can format the column as %m.%Y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create dates you can for example use the lubridate package:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(date = c(5.2016999999999998 5.2016999999999998 5.2016999999999998 5.2016999999999998 2.2017000000000002 9.2017000000000007))

df %>%
  mutate(date = dmy(paste0("01.", round(date, 4))))
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need to first fix the problems of the floating numbers in order to apply your solution to create a date.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can use round().